# How to implement GetThreadContext in Linux/Unix?

Tags: linux, windows, cpu-registers

GetThreadContext is a Windows API.

```
BOOL WINAPI GetThreadContext(
_In_     HANDLE hThread,
_Inout_  LPCONTEXT lpContext
);
```

I wonder that how to implement it in linux.
How to retrieves the register information of the specified thread in Linux?

Like this:

```
pthread_create(thread_id, ...);
...
func(thread_id, reg_info)
{
    //get the reg_info by thread_id.
    ??
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A Linux-specific way of getting thread info is to use `get_thread_area()`. From the `get_thread_area()` man page:

> `get_thread_area()` returns an entry in the current thread's Thread Local Storage (TLS)        array. The index of the entry corresponds to the value of `u_info->entry_number`, passed in by the user.  If the  value  is  in  bounds, `get_thread_area()` copies the corresponding TLS entry into the area pointed to by `u_info`.

But, if you want to read the register value you need to take help of inline assembly. Fox example, to retrieve the value of esp you can use the following inline assembly:

```
unsigned sp;
__asm __volatile("movl %%esp, %0" : "=r" (sp));
return sp;
```

In this way, you can extract `ebp`, `eip` etc. Hope this will help!