# Anti-debugging: gdb does not write 0xcc byte for breakpoints. Any idea why?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

I am learning some anti-debugging techniques on Linux and found a snippet of code for checking 0xcc byte in memory to detect the breakpoints in gdb. Here is that code:

```
     if ((*(volatile unsigned *)((unsigned)foo + 3) & 0xff) == 0xcc)   
     {
                    printf("BREAKPOINT\n");
                    exit(1);
      }

     foo();
```

But it does not work. I even tried to set a breakpoint on foo() function and observe the contents in memory, but did not see any 0xcc byte written for breakpoint. Here is what I did:

```
(gdb) b foo
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804846a: file p4.c, line 8.
(gdb) x/x 0x804846a
0x804846a <foo+6>:  0xe02404c7
(gdb) x/16x 0x8048460
0x8048460 <frame_dummy+32>: 0x90c3c9d0  0x83e58955  0x04c718ec  0x0485e024
0x8048470 <foo+12>: 0xfefae808  0xc3c9ffff  .....
```

As you can see, there seems to be no 0xcc byte written on the entry point of foo() function. Does anyone know what's going on or where I might be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: There is an interesting article on this topic 
`How debugger works`, take a look at this part of the article `The magic behind INT 3`: http://www.alexonlinux.com/how-debugger-works#the_magic_behind_int_3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Second part is easily explained (as Flortify correctly stated):
GDB shows original memory contents, not the breakpoint "bytes". In default mode it actually even removes breakpoints when debugger suspends and re-inserts them before continuing. Users typically want to see their code, not strange modified instructions used for breakpoints.

With your C code you missed breakpoint for few bytes. GDB sets breakpoint *after* [function prologue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue), because function prologue is not typically what gdb users want to see. So, if you put break to foo, actual breakpoint will be typically located few bytes after that (depends on prologue code itself that is function dependent as it may or might not have to save stack pointer, frame pointer and so on). But it is easy to check. I used this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)main;

    for (j=0; j<4; j++) {
        printf("%p: ",p);
        for (i=0; i<16; i++)
            printf("%.2x ", *p++);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If we run this program by itself it prints:

> ```
> 0x40057d: 55 48 89 e5 48 83 ec 10 48 c7 45 f8 7d 05 40 00
> 0x40058d: c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00 eb 5a 48 8b 45 f8 48 89 c6
> 0x40059d: bf 84 06 40 00 b8 00 00 00 00 e8 b4 fe ff ff c7
> 0x4005ad: 45 f0 00 00 00 00 eb 27 48 8b 45 f8 48 8d 50 01
> ```

Now we run it in gdb (output re-formatted for SO).

> ```
> (gdb) break main
> Breakpoint 1 at 0x400585: file ../bp.c, line 6.
> (gdb) info break
> Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What
> 1       breakpoint     keep y   0x0000000000400585 in main at ../bp.c:6
> (gdb) disas/r main,+32
> Dump of assembler code from 0x40057d to 0x40059d:
>   0x000000000040057d (main+0):  55                        push %rbp
>   0x000000000040057e (main+1):  48 89 e5                  mov %rsp,%rbp
>   0x0000000000400581 (main+4):  48 83 ec 10               sub $0x10,%rsp
>   0x0000000000400585 (main+8):  48 c7 45 f8 7d 05 40 00   movq $0x40057d,-0x8(%rbp)
>   0x000000000040058d (main+16): c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00      movl $0x0,-0xc(%rbp)
>   0x0000000000400594 (main+23): eb 5a                     jmp 0x4005f0 
>   0x0000000000400596 (main+25): 48 8b 45 f8               mov -0x8(%rbp),%rax
>   0x000000000040059a (main+29): 48 89 c6                  mov %rax,%rsi
> End of assembler dump.
> ```

With this we verified, that program is printing correct bytes. But this also shows that breakpoint has been inserted at 0x400585 (that is after function prologue), not at first instruction of function.
If we now run program under gdb (with run) and then "continue" after breakpoint is hit, we get this output:

> ```
> (gdb) cont
> Continuing.
> 0x40057d: 55 48 89 e5 48 83 ec 10 cc c7 45 f8 7d 05 40 00 
> 0x40058d: c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00 eb 5a 48 8b 45 f8 48 89 c6 
> 0x40059d: bf 84 06 40 00 b8 00 00 00 00 e8 b4 fe ff ff c7 
> 0x4005ad: 45 f0 00 00 00 00 eb 27 48 8b 45 f8 48 8d 50 01
> ```

This now shows 0xcc being printed for address 9 bytes into main.

Comment: Why didn't gdb remove the `0xCC` byte after the breakpoint was hit?

Comment: This is by design. GDB does not remove "standard" breakpoints one they are hit. Temporary breakpoints (inserted with tbreak) are permanently removed once hit, though.

Answer (score 4):

If your hardware supports it, GDB may be using [**Hardware Breakpoints**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint#Hardware), which do not patch the code.

While I have not confirmed this via any official docs, [this page](http://haifux.org/lectures/210/gdb_-_customize_it.html) indicates that

> By default, gdb attempts to use hardware-assisted break-points.

Since you indicate expecting `0xCC` bytes, I'm assuming you're running on x86 hardware, as the `int3` opcode is `0xCC`.  x86 processors have a set of [debug registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register) `DR0`-`DR3`, where you can program the address of data to cause a breakpoint exception. `DR7` is  a bitfield which controls the behavior of the breakpoints, and `DR6` indicates the status.

The debug registers can only be read/written from Ring 0 (kernel mode). That means that the kernel manages these registers for you (via the `ptrace` API, I believe.)

However, for the sake of anti-debugging, all hope is not lost! On Windows, the [`GetThreadContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679362.aspx) API allows you to get (a copy) of the `CONTEXT` for a (stopped) thread. This structure includes the contents of the `DRx` registers. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480853/how-to-implement-getthreadcontext-in-linux-unix) is about how to implement the same on Linux.

Comment: I think you are wrong when say: `While I have not confirmed this via any official docs, this page indicates that`. This page indicates it for watchpoints, not breakpoints. On the contrary user1726119 asks about breakpoints. By the way, GDB's official doc also says this about watchpoints: `gdb sets a hardware watchpoint if possible.` http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html#Set-Watchpoints

Answer (score 2):

This may also be a white lie that GDB is telling you... there may be a breakpoint there in RAM but GDB has noted what was there beforehand (so it can restore it later) and is showing you that, instead of the true contents of RAM.

Of course, it could also be using **Hardware Breakpoints**, which is a facility available on some processors.  Setting h/w breakpoints is done by telling the processor the address it should watch out for (and trigger a breakpoint interrupt if it gets hit by the program counter while executing code).

Comment: While your first paragraph may explain the behavior he's seeing while observing memory via GDB (*I thought this too, at first*), it does not explain the program observing itself.

Comment: No, the original question **did not** say he ever ran the program under GDB with a breakpoint set **and** had it observe itself.  The question describes writing a program that observes itself, and then setting a breakpoint in GDB and then **using GDB** to look for the breakpoint in memory.  Only.

Comment: @dbrank0 Gave the best answer, showing a program observing itself **while** running under GDB **with** a breakpoint set.